# Help upgrading old PC from 2012

Tags: graphics-cards, pc, desktop, upgrade

I have an old PC from ca 2012. The motherboard is an ASROCK Z77 Extreme6 (https://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/Z77%20Extreme6/). CPU is a i5-3570K (1155 socket), a Gigabyte Gforce GTX 650 Ti OC 2GB GDDR5 and 16G Ram (Corsair).

PC parts picker tells me the only CPU upgrade is an i7 3770K, but also tells me a RTX 3090 would be compatible with this MB. Is this true?

I am planning on using this PC for some deep learning and instead of going out and buying a complete new rig I was wondering if simply upgrading the GPU to a newer model like the RTX 2090 or 3080 is a. possible or b. even worth it.
I am not planning on doing any heavy deep faking, I just want to play around with some classifiers and style transfers.

The motherboard supports PCIe 16 and I would of course upgrade the PSU as well if I go for such an extreme GPU upgrade. I am mainly worried if a new GPU would be "slowed" by the rest of the PC.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your mobo, PCPartPicker is totally right. Your mobo is limited (in cpu terms) to the i7 gen 3 and DDR3 RAM. Since PCIe is backwards compatible with all versions, you can indeed get a 3090ti if you really want to. I would still reccomend not getting a 3090 because of PSU constraints and get a 2060 Super instead. It still has Tensor cores used for deep learning and way faster than your current 650ti.